# Caching (ETags and If-None-Match) in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

Are there any good examples showing how to integrate client-side caching? I'm talking about generating ETags, using the "If-None-Match" headers, etc.

On the WebAPI side there's CacheCow, is there something similar for ServiceStack?

Answer (score 1):

There is now improved support around client-side Caching from v4.0.56 with the introduction of the `CacheResponseAttribute` and the `CachedServiceClient`

More can be found here in the docs
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/CacheResponse-Attribute
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Cache-Aware-Clients